# nginx writre log to sqlite

Tags: nginx, lua

please could you help me
can I let NGINX to write access log directly to sqlite table which I will make the same field as in access.log?

I know I can try to do it with LUA, but I do not know how to put the trigger to nginx to run LUA script on every record in access.log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the [log_by_lua](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#log_by_lua) phase to write access logs, as it runs last and allows you to access variables like upstream_response_time, etc.